# How do I create a class to help me log my application user activity? (clean coding and code refactoring question)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, refactoring

Currently when a user performs a CRUD action I log it in the database:

```
var user = User.Identity.Name;
var log = (from l in db.AppLogs where l.UserName == user select l).ToList();
var logresult = (from lr in log select lr).LastOrDefault();
var loggedUser = (from lu in db.AMProfiles where lu.UserName == logresult.UserName select lu).SingleOrDefault();
var logAppName = "My Application";
var logRequestType = "Create New Movie - " + Movie.Name;

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    AMLog userLog = new AMLog
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now,                 
        UserId = Convert.ToInt32(loggedUser.EmployeeId),
        AppName = logAppName,
        RequestType = logRequestType,
        LogId = logresult.Id
    };
    db.MADMovies.Add(mADMovies);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem here is that I know this is not very clean, repetitive and that there should be a better way of doing this.

What I would like to do instead is use a class that gets called when a CRUD action is performed. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use a custom ActionFilter to accomplish things like this.

Get some types going or whatever you need:

```
public enum AuditEventType 
{
    LoggedIn,
    LoggedOut,
    ViewedPage,
    Etc
}
```

Create an action filter class:

```
public class AuditEvent : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    AuditEventType Type;

    public AuditEvent(AuditEventType type) 
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public override OnActionExecuted() 
    {
         //log user name and audit event to db
    }
}
```

Decorate your controller method you want to log:

```
[HttpPost]
[AuditEvent(AuditEventType.LoggedIn)]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) 
{
   //do login logic
}
```